# MS CRM 2013 adds version number to WebResources of script type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm

I have found strange issue in MS CRM 2013, and since it seems to be by design, I need help to find a way around it.

The issue is it's impossible to call `getScript` jQuery method from WebResource.

The CRM adds version string to the url, and this causes request fail with error `500`.

For example, when I'm trying to call: `/Organization/WebResources/Synchronization.js`

The CRM turns this request into following: `/Organization/WebResources/Synchronization.js?_=1402918931398` and it fails with server error `500`.

Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
var settings = {
    url: "/Organization/WebResources/Synchronization.js",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (data) {
       console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log("error");
    }
};

$.ajax(settings);
```

Could you please point me, how I can find out when `URL` is changed?

Comment: just a note, the number is added in order to force the browser to use the latest version of the webresource, otherwise the browser cache will load old versions

Comment: In CRM 2013 adding this numbers leads to server error 500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns, that this is `jQuery` caching feature.

If caching will be turned on in settings object, the issue will disappear. Like this:

```
var settings = {
    url: "/Organization/WebResources/Synchronization.js",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (data) {
       console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log("error");
    }
};
```

Comment: did you check if with `cache: true` you get the latest version?

Comment: @GuidoPreite No. I'm relying on cache. This is not good, in general case, but in this particular, could be fine, I don't expect that `js` file to change. And once again, even if I wanted to get un-cached version, CRM 2013 does not allow me.